# Cannot hear program audio when running them as root

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, blender

Edit: alright I've been a naughty boy, no more root, I'm going to make another question that this time, actually reflects my issue.

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu (recently upgraded from 18.04 to 22.04) and Linux.
Recently I've been using blender (3.3.1 LT). In order to get it to recognize my GPU, I run blender as root with either:

`sudo blender` (installed from snap)

or

`sudo ./blender` (within the directory downloaded from blender.org)

If it helps, I have the preferences within blender set to "PulseAudio".

Without doing this, it will inform me I cannot use AMD HIP:

> Requires discrete AMD GPU and RDNA architecture and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer

When running as root, I have both the option to select my RX 5600 xt and my Ryzen 3600.
Doing both of these works fine, however then I can no longer hear the audio.

Comment: It is never a good idea to run any app as root. For install OK but on day to day never.

Comment: alright, do you have any idea on how i can get the software to recognize my GPU?

Comment: There is nothing in your question about a GPU. Maybe you need to review and edit the question.

Comment: Alright, I'll make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the good way to break your system, or at the very least your personal account. *Never* run graphical programs with `sudo`.

Comment: alright alright

Comment: have a nice day :P